# R predict giving unexpected results

Tags: r, predict

I'm running a predict function of:

predict(model, df_smooth)

Where:

model <- lm(pct ~ poly(spread_favorite, 2), win_pct_by_point_spread_underdog)

df_smooth <- data.frame(spread_favorite = seq(-26, -1, 0.5))

The df_smooth table looks like:

|  | spread_favorite |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | -26.0 |
| 2 | -25.5 |

and goes on until spread_favorite = 0.

The output of the predict statement is:

|  |  |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | -0.013 |
| 2 | -0.0128 |

What I would like to get in the predict table is, instead of the index column, the spread_favorite being the returned column, like:

| spread_favorite |  |
| --- | --- |
| -26.0 | -0.013 |
| -25.5 | -0.0128 |

The two questions would be, is there an easy way to get the spread_favorite column to return instead of the index, and what would be the best way to create a column name for the result column?

Comment: Simply modify the `df_smooth` dataframe, e.g. `df_smooth$Result <- predict(model, df_smooth)`.  Don't use a column name that is in your model formula, or you'll get different results the next time you run it.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Still very new to this R thing so I appreciate your help on this.